# BIRT 4.4 {fn dbDate} error in syntax

Tags: sql, birt

An old BIRT report was using the `{fn dbDate}` syntax..

Namely:

```
WHERE
    CAT.STANDARDS_CATEGORY_ID IN (select DESCENDANTID from DM_COMPONENT_TREE dct where ANCESTORID in (<in_clause>))
    AND
    (FACT.PHASE_COMPONENT_ID IS NULL
        OR (
            LP.PHASE_START_DATE <= {fn dbDate}
            AND (LP.PHASE_END_DATE IS NULL OR LP.PHASE_END_DATE >= {fn dbDate})
        )
    )
```

My team has upgraded to BIRT 4.4.

The report is erroring out when it is run:

> org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: An exception occurred during processing. Please see the following message for details:
>   Failed to prepare the query execution for the data set: Reference Data Set
>   Cannot get the result set metadata.
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: SQL statement does not return a ResultSet object.
>   SQL error #1:Incorrect syntax near '}'.

Could there be a syntax change between the old and new version of BIRT?

If not, what could be the problem?

Comment: Never seen that syntax before. Could it be that this is not a BIRT problem, but that it's caused by change in the JDBC driver and/or DB version?

Comment: My team and I worked out what the problem was.  The company that developed our COTs application which we use in our team used a script in BIRT to replace the getdate() function with {fn dbDate}. We removed this piece of script and used the normal getDate() function and it worked.  Thank you for your comment.